# error compiling: linux/module.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation, kernel

I've written a simple module:

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define MODULE
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/module.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk("Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk("Goodbye\n");
}
```

and compiling it with this command:

```
cc -c hello.c
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
 linux/module.h: No such file or directory
```

any suggestions?

EDIT: 
I used this commad:

```
cc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/include -c hello.c
```

and it goes one step ahead, now I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from hello.c:3:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/include/linux/linkage.h:5:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: yes..I've kernel header installed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First thing you need the *[kernel sources](http://www.kernel.org/)*. Many confuse user space headers and kernel space headers because many of them have the same folder structure. Most of the distros only have the user space headers and not the kernel space ones.

And *generally* `make` is used to build a kernel module and not a bare `cc`. Follow the simple step-by-step explained `Hello World` kernel module given [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html)

Comment: thanks a lot... I made the make file and it worked. Thanks again

Comment: @PavanManjunath I have created a makefile just as shown in tutorial but I am getting this message   make: Nothing to be done for `all'. I am using ubuntu and have linux-header installed.

Comment: @user606669 
There can be many reasons for your problem. See if this helps http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1795434 or may be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561640/make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all

Answer (score 4):

Source file name is basic.c

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
/*MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");*/
static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

=====================================

## now make file for ubuntu

At first type on ur terminal that $(uname -r) then u will get the version..
that is using on ur system

```
obj-m +=basic.o

KDIR =//usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic

all:
 $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
 rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

================================================

## **To run the code**

```
$sudo insmod basic.ko
$dmesg
u will get the output
$sudo rmmod basic.ko
$dmesg
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the kernel headers; they are usually in `/usr/include/` if installed.

Unless you are using a source-based distro or built your own kernel chances are good they are not installed by default; use your distro's package manager to install them. The package is often called `linux-headers`.

Comment: Nope, he needs the kernels internal headers, not those exported to user space.

Comment: do I need to install kernel headers? I had the directory /usr/include/ module.h is not present in it

Comment: thatnks...I've installed the kernel headers but now get another error, see the updated question. Can you help on this?

Comment: I've got it working using the make file. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need the kernel build environment (selection of scripts, header and Makefiles) usually this is reachable through /lib/modules/*version*/build (a symlink to it) if a kernel has been installed already. Otherwise, the directory is the build directory (the one where System.map is in). Full sources are *not* needed (smart distros recognize this), and neither is /usr/include/whatever.

You also *must* use kbuild; calling `cc -I` is not enough, and has not been for more than 10 years. You start off with a `Kbuild` file:

```
obj-m += mymodule.o
```

and a `Makefile`:

```
kdir=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
all:
        make -C ${kdir} M=$$PWD
modules_install clean:
        make -C ${kdir} M=$$PWD $@
```

and then utilize `make`.

#defining `__KERNEL__` and `MODULE` is also pointless, because that is already set by kbuild if needed.

Comment: thanks a lot...I used the make file in the tutorial pointed by @Pavan Manjunath and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux distros don't install kernel headers as default. Look for a package kernel-headers or something similar.