# How do we compile kernel code in C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am new to C and Linux. I am trying to compile the below code but it gives some fatal error while compiling. Any help on fixing this appreciated.

Here is the code `measurecpu.c`:

```
#include <linux/module.h>      
#include <linux/kernel.h>      
#include <linux/init.h>         
#include <linux/hardirq.h>
#include <linux/preempt.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

uint64_t start, end;
int i=0;
asm volatile ("CPUID \ n \ t" "RDTSC \ n \ t" "mov %%edx, %0 \ n \ t" "mov %%eax, %1 \ n \ t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)::  "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");

for(i=0; i<200000;i++) {}

asm volatile ("RDTSCP \ n \ t" "mov %%edx, %0 \ n \ t" "mov %%eax, %1 \ n \ t" "CPUID \ n \ t": "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1)::  "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");


start = ( ((uint64_t)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low );
 end = ( ((uint64_t)cycles_high1 << 32) | cycles_low1 );
printk(KERN_INFO " \ n function execution time is %llu clock cycles",(end - start));

}
```

I am trying to compile it this way:

```
gcc -c -O2 -W -Wall -isystem /lib/modules/'uname -r'/build/include -D_KERNEL_ -DMODULE measurecpu.c
```

I get this error:

```
measurecpu.c:1:32: fatal error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/module.h>      
                                ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: If you get build errors then you can't get segmentation faults.

Comment: oops i meant how do we build the code. sorry for the wrong wording. will edit

Comment: /lib/modules/'uname -r'/build/include <- I think you need **backticks** here. Or use $(uname -r). 'uname -r' will just be that string, no substitution is performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to compile it this way 
>   gcc -c -O2 -W -Wall -isystem /lib/modules/'uname -r'/build/include -D_KERNEL_ -DMODULE measurecpu.c

Usually the way to compile a kernel module is to use the kernel build system - ie you use `make` instead of `gcc` directly. You need to create a `Makefile` and specify the object, which is the line `obj-m := measurecpu.o` in your case. After that in the same directory, issue the `make` command, which will yield the kernel object file **measurecpu.ko**

```
# If KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := measurecpu.o

# Otherwise we were called directly from the command
# line; invoke the kernel build system.
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules clean

endif
```

Note that kernel module is not user space program, so you cannot *just run it*. You will need to tell the kernel about that kernel module via `insmod`, and check the results via `dmesg`.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message clearly says, the compiler couldn't find the header file `module.h` in the folder `linux`.

Refer to this post: [error compiling: linux/module.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10126134/1196549)