# make: nothing can be done for 'all' error

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, gnu-make

I have been trying all the answers that are posted in stack overflow previously. Nothing worked for me.
Below is the make file:

```
export IFT_DIR=./ift
export OPF_DIR=./ift/LibOPF

all:    msp_bin

FLAGS= -O6 -Wall

$(IFT_DIR)/lib/libift.a:
$(MAKE) -C $(IFT_DIR) 

msp_bin: msp_bin.c $(IFT_DIR)/lib/libift.a
    gcc $(FLAGS) msp_bin.c -o msp_bin -I $(IFT_DIR)/include I$(IFT_DIR)/LibOPF/include -L $(IFT_DIR)/lib -lift -lm -lz
clean:
     del -f msp_bin *.a *~
     $(MAKE) clean -C $(IFT_DIR)
```

and I get the error saying "make: nothing can be done for all."

Comment: Indentation is crucial, but nothing is indented in your post. Is that the same in your makefile or an error when posting it here?

Comment: I am not sure about your question. I am actually trying to code that I downloaded. I have makefile in the folder along with a msp_bin.c file and msp_bin file (it has no extension). The readme file says "just type make and it will compile and generate msp_bin". It also asks zlib1g. I have installed it.

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't already built? Make avoids rebuilding files that are already built and emits a similar message when it finds it doesn't need to do anything

Comment: Consider the possibility that the software wasn't written for MS Windows and that you can't compile it there. An executable without a file extension ".exe" is such an indicator. The use of "del" instead of "rm" is a counterindicator. Anyhow, questions like that need a [mcve]. However, consider filing a bug report at the supplier of the code as well. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: _nothing can be done_ is not an actual error message generated by `make`.  Please cut and paste the command you invoked and the _exact_ error message you get when you run `make`.

Comment: Did you try `all:\n\tmake msp_bin` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having a problem with the indentation. 
The line right after your rules need to have a Tab, or it won't work.

example:

```
msp_bin: msp_bin.c $(IFT_DIR)/lib/libift.a
gcc $(FLAGS) msp_bin.c -o msp_bin -I $(IFT_DIR)/include ...
```

shoutld be:

```
msp_bin: msp_bin.c $(IFT_DIR)/lib/libift.a
    gcc $(FLAGS) msp_bin.c -o msp_bin -I $(IFT_DIR)/include ...
```

Check out this answer too: [make: Nothing to be done for `all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561640/make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all)

Comment: Sorry. You are right! I dint paste the code here in the proper way. I edited my question now !